# Why can't I cast to B*?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to cast to B* using operators but it's not working. Why? Thanks.

```
struct B;

struct A {
    A() = default;

    operator (B *)() {
        return new B();
    }
};

struct B { B() = default; };

int main() {

    A a;

    B *b = a;

}
```

I get the error: `cannot convert 'A' to 'B*' in initialization`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with `operator (B*)()` ? I generally use `operator B*()`, and your statement won't even compile on my toolchain. The error you showed is the *last* error in my output log with your code; not the first (which is "C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations" on your operator decl line.

Comment: This may be due to the incomplete definition of B. You can't create a `new` B... just guessing.

Comment: What compiler are you using that doesn´t complain about your _real_ errors?

Comment: @K-ballo- I compiled this with g++ 4.6.3 and didn't get errors about the parentheses.

Comment: @templatetypedef: You should try with a more recent version, and report the issue if its still there

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with your code. First, the parenthesis around `B*` are wrong, just do:

```
operator B*() {...}
```

and it should probably be a `const` member function.

Additionally, you are trying to create a new instance of a type `B` before `B` is defined. You can´t do that with an *incomplete type*, just define `B` before `A`.

After those errors are removed, your code works as expected.

Comment: So why was this compiling with the parentheses and giving the error later?  What was the compiler interpreting `(B*)` as?

Comment: @templatetypedef: No clue, its a syntax error, I wonder the same and have asked the OP what compiler is he using...